# BaseAdapter with AlphabetIndexer

Tags: c#, android

I have created a custom Adapter called: `ContactsAdapter` which inherits from `BaseAdapter` and implements `ISectionIndexer`.

Is it possible to implement an `AlphabetIndexer` on the custom adapter without making use of a `ICursor`? Reason being, the adapter makes use of a `List<T>` to stores all the items.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer; **yes** you can do it without making use of `ICursor`. Basically you implement the interface `ISectionIndexer` on your `BaseAdapter<T>`

`ISectionIndexer` implementation consists of the following methods:

```
    public int GetPositionForSection(int section)
    {
        ...
    }

    public int GetSectionForPosition(int position)
    {
        ...
    }

    public Java.Lang.Object[] GetSections()
    {
        ...
    }
```

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

What about sorting the list before setting it to the adapter?

Like:

```
Collections.sort(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

The object list that you want to sort needs to implement `Comparable`

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I'm not exactly sure how this will provide me with a ICursor. Many thanks again!